# Advanced SUM query

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have the following query:

```
    SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j1 
UNION 
SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j2
UNION
SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j3 
UNION
SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j4
```

which gives me the following result:

```
pont 
0
10
19
43
```

i just want to sum these results! tried using sum() this way but didn't work:

```
SELECT SUM(
SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j1 
UNION 
SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j2
UNION
SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j3 
UNION
SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j4
    ) AS totalpont
```

am i doing the SUM query wrong? if so, how can i do it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the syntax.

**This will work**.

```
SELECT SUM(point) AS totalpont
      FROM
    (SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j1 
    UNION 
    SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j2
    UNION
    SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j3 
    UNION
    SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j4) T
```

Hope this helps

Comment: ok, now i get a "Every derived table must have its own alias", what do i do?

Comment: for more info 
http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2012/06/23/derived-table-aliases/

Answer (score 1):

Make the result using `UNION` as a sub-query and then do the sum.

**Query**

```
SELECT SUM(t.pont) as totalPont from
(
    SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios 
    WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j1 
    UNION 
    SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios 
    WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j2
    UNION
    SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios 
    WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j3 
    UNION
    SELECT jogador.pont from jogador,usuarios 
    WHERE email='like' and jogador.id=usuarios.j4
)t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test this, but it will be something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(all.pont)
FROM 
(
    SELECT jogador.pont 
    FROM jogador,usuarios 
    WHERE email='like' 
    AND jogador.id=usuarios.j1 
    UNION 
    SELECT jogador.pont 
    FROM jogador,usuarios 
    WHERE email='like' 
    AND jogador.id=usuarios.j2
    UNION
    SELECT jogador.pont 
    FROM jogador,usuarios
    WHERE email='like' 
    AND jogador.id=usuarios.j3 
    UNION
    SELECT jogador.pont 
    FROM jogador,usuarios 
    WHERE email='like' 
    AND jogador.id=usuarios.j4
) AS all
```